# Disable Cors on mobile Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, cors

I need to disable cors on chrome mobile device, i found this tutorial on how to do it :
https://aleksgrunwald.wordpress.com/2019/12/08/disable-cors-policy-on-android-chrome/

first i download the Android Debug Bridge (adb), i activated the devloper mode on my device,
and connected it to my PC via a USB cable, now i can see my device when i call: `$ adb devices`.
i added a file called : `/data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line` in witch i added this line :

```
echo chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default
```

but when i try : `chrome://version/`
I dont see --disable-web-security in the command line.

NB: i dont want to put any cors header, it's not a production env and i just need to debug without cors.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it? i'm encountering the same problem